# How to return the result of a method from a Mocked Repository in Java Unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, repository

So I'm testing this class, that has this `addAll` method that basically stores a generated list into the repository.

I would like to know how can I return the `savedList` variable in order to perform some assertions in my test.

The `list` is filled with some data from the object `request`, and also from performing some queries to the repository (findBy).

```
public class MyClass{

    private final MyRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public List<B> addAll(A request) {
        List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // Logic: fill list with data from `request` variable and also performing findBy on the repository

        List<B> savedList = repository.saveAll(list);

        return savedList;
    }
}
```

In my test I have mocked the repository in order to return the objects that I want when performing the `findBy`, but I don't know how to mock the `saveAll` method but returning the variable that is being generated in the method.

As you may understand, mocking the `saveAll` method with a list created in the test would not make much sense since the point of returning the `savedList`, is checking the change on the values that have been stored.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for mocking methods is to avoid connections to other Units.
So if you want to test `addAll()` its totally fine to mock the result of `saveAll()`.

If you want to check the result of `saveAll()` that sounds like a integration test to me.

Btw the `addAll()` should not implement any kind of businesslogic.

Hope that helped ;)

Comment: Hi @mhdl ! Thank you for your answer! 
No, I definetely don't want to test the `saveAll` method. I just want to test the small logic of the `addAll` method and how the `list` is generated. And in order to perform the assertions on the generated `list`, which becomes the `savedList` after the `saveAll` method, I need to mock the result from the `saveAll` method and I don't know how to mock it to return the `list`.
And yes, I agree that it shouldn't have business logic, but it's just a simple if statement to update one field in case it finds the object in the repository!
Thanks!